# How to access a variable inside a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity

So for example im trying to execute a swap on 1inch with the [OneSplitAudit smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/1split.eth#code) but after i execute the swap() function i dont know how to retrieve the "amounts" value it returns to me. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean via web3js or ethersjs, you could probably look through the events emitted and search for the token.

Using ethersjs this would look something like:

```js
let tx = await contract.swap(token1, token2, amount);
let receipt = await tx.wait();
let logs = receipt.events;
```

Comment: thanks. i mean in solidity btw. anyway i tried to put the return value on a variable, look this `//swap WETH to DAI in uniswap
        amountreceived = UniswapV2Router02.swapExactTokensForTokens(1000, 1,[WETHaddress,DAIaddress], address(this),1762389590);
        //swap DAI to WETH in 1inch
        OneSplitAudit.getExpectedReturn(DAIaddress, WETHaddress, amountreceived, 1,0);
        OneSplitAudit.swap(DAIaddress, WETHaddress,amountreceived,0,distribution,0);`